# Need to find contents of Solaris zfs snapshot

Tags: solaris, zfs, snapshot

I have zfs snapshot and I want to view the contents of particular snapshot. This is for Solaris 10.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [Oracle Solaris documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbiqe/index.html):

> Snapshots of file systems are accessible in the `.zfs/snapshot`
> directory within the root of the file system. For example, if
> `tank/home/ahrens` is mounted on `/home/ahrens`, then the
> `tank/home/ahrens@thursday` snapshot data is accessible in the
> `/home/ahrens/.zfs/snapshot/thursday` directory.